# Trying to get a button to work as a submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to figure out how to make this HTML submit button work correctly. Below is the code for the submit button:

```
<form action ="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://icustomer.apsresource.com/ipad_apps/survey/user/APSSurvey.plist">
    <button type="submit" name="Download" value="download" onclick="JavaScript:alert('You will be downloading the APS Resource iPAD PRODUCT SURVEY.')" style="width:255px; height:310px; -webkit-appearance: none; -webkit-border-radius:0px;">
        <img src="apple.png"  />
    </button>
</form>
```

When the button is clicked, it is supposed to open up the URL in the "action" part in the form tag. However, all I get is the JS pop-up, but no URL is opened (looking at the console, a GET function is triggered, then instantly canceled). IS there something I need to add/remove in order for this to work?

Comment: Are you trying to show a popup AND submit the form in the background, or on closing the alert? Are there any form elements in the form? I would try using a more standard action URL to test.

Comment: What is the response to the GET request? 500? 404? That will help explain the problem.

Comment: @mtaube the GET function, according to the (Chrome) browser console is canceled (No error number). Additionally, it seems that a question mark has been added to the URL, so it now like this: ?Download=[rest of URL].

Comment: Have you tried a normal URL as a test? It sounds like the browser does not like yours.

Comment: A normal URL works fine. I'll need to confirm that this is the correct URL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit the form with the onclick event

```
onclick="alert('You will be downloading the APS Resource iPAD PRODUCT SURVEY.');this.form.submit();"
```

You don't need to put the work JavaScript in your event either.

BTW, you don't really need to have this.form.submit() at all.  I took your original and removed JavaScript from the onlick and changed the action and your code works fine.  I'm not sure what `itms-services://` is but it's not a valid HTTP protocol like http:// or https://.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robbertv/8jgoL9qq/) illustrating this.

Comment: This works for the button, but I still see the GET error. The link places a question mark on the URL I need.